# Excel 2 Databases = 1 Diagram in

Tags: excel

I wanna create a Diagram, but here is the Problem.

In Worksheet 1:

```
Date   | Value1 
-------+---------
1.1.12 | 3
1.1.12 | 4
1.1.12 | 5
2.1.12 | 6
2.1.12 | 4
```

In Worksheet 2:

```
Date    | Value3 | Value4
--------+--------+---------
1.1.12  | 4      | 5 
2.1.12  | 5      | 7
```

The Diagram should show `Sum(Value1)/Value3` for each Day. 
But I don't get it because the Dates are different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a new column to your `workseet2` with this formula:

```
= SUMIF(Worksheet1!A:B; A2; B:B) / C2
```

Now you have a column with your needed result, and now use it in your diagram.